# "android.intent.extra.durationLimit"

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi
 the above constant have no effect in Htc phone ,i have used that one in my video recording ,except Htc phone it work fine

Comment: did you find any solution? I have the same issue on HTC.

Answer (score 1):

What is the SDK version available in your device? Remember this constant has been added only from **API level 8** which means it would work only from devices that run **2.2 SDK** and above

Comment: API LEVEL 7 ,but it work fine , in all other phone except in HTC

Comment: Till the time it is mentioned in the official documentation you can only call it "undocumented".You cannot rely on an undocumented API. It might or might not work since any manufacturer who port Android to their devices can remove them. Try it on a device running API level 8 and check. That would be my advice

Comment: I am working on android 2.3.3 this is greater than API level 7 still my code is not working in HTC devices but working fine on all devices